# Kevin Brothaler OpenGL ES 2 tutorial code is wrong?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I got a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1937785343) "Pragmatic OpenGL ES 2 for Android" by Kevin Brothaler. I just start to reading it and doing tutorials.

Everything was fine until the tutorial in 4th chapter, about adding colors and shades.

So 3rd chapter code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/danil_minibaev/vedroid-ogl-es2-tutorials/commits/13a9a078e15e136ed3b9e5e4442641e9c0f84daf) (there are lot of stuff so I added a link).
Everything was fine.

And in the 4th chapter we are changing the way which this stuff is drawn and changing shaders.

And there are just black screen instead of such nice picture
[image]

First, we've changed the shaders

Vertex shader

```
attribute vec4 a_Position;

attribute vec4 a_Color;
varying vec4 v_Color;
void main()
{
    v_Color = a_Color;

    gl_Position = a_Position;
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;
}
```

Frament shader

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 v_Color;

void main(){
     gl_FragColor = v_Color;
}
```

Also we added new stuff in Render class and deleted some too.

Variables

```
private static final int POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT=2;
private static final int BYTES_PER_FLOAT=4;
private static final String A_COLOR="a_Color";
private static final int COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT=3;
private static final int STRIDE = (POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT+COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT)*BYTES_PER_FLOAT;

private int aColorLocation;
```

Changing methods this way ([thats](https://bitbucket.org/danil_minibaev/vedroid-ogl-es2-tutorials/src/13a9a078e15e136ed3b9e5e4442641e9c0f84daf/src/com/airhockey/android/AirHockeyRenderer.java?at=default) how it was before)

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        String vertexShaderSource = TextResourceReader.readTextFileFromResource(context,  R.raw.simple_vertex_shader);
        String fragmentShaderSource = TextResourceReader.readTextFileFromResource(context, R.raw.simple_fragment_shader);
        int vertexShader = ShaderHelper.compileVertexShader(vertexShaderSource);
        int fragmentShader = ShaderHelper.compileFragmentShader(fragmentShaderSource);
        program = ShaderHelper.linkProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);

        if(LoggerConfig.ON){
            ShaderHelper.validateProgram(program);
        }

        glUseProgram(program);

        aPositionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, A_POSITION);

        aColorLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, A_COLOR);



        vertexData.position(0);

        glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation,POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT,GL_FLOAT,
                false, STRIDE, vertexData);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(aColorLocation);

        vertexData.position(POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT);

        glVertexAttribPointer(aColorLocation, COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT,GL_FLOAT,
                false,STRIDE,vertexData);


    }

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);

    //с 6, 2 пары
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES,6,2);
    //Draw the first mallet blue.

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,8,1);
    //Draw the second mallet red.
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,9,1);


}

public AirHockeyRenderer(Context context){

    this.context=context;


    float[] tableVerticesWithTriangles={
            //TriangleFan
            0f, 0f, 1f, 1f, 1f,
            -0.5f,-0.5f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f,
            0.5f,-0.5f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f,
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f,
            -0.5f,-0.5f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f,

            //Line1
            -0.5f,0f,1f, 0f, 0f,
            0.5f,0f, 1f, 0f, 0f,
            //Mallets
            0f,-0.25f,0f,0f,1f,
            0f, 0.25f,1f,0f,0f
    };





    vertexData=ByteBuffer
            .allocateDirect(tableVerticesWithTriangles.length*BYTES_PER_FLOAT)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            .asFloatBuffer();


    vertexData.put(tableVerticesWithTriangles);


}
```

Whats wrong? Why there are black screen? Maybe I miss something?

Full repo is [here](https://bitbucket.org/danil_minibaev/vedroid-ogl-es2-tutorials/src/13a9a078e15e?at=default)

UPD:
I run [this](https://bitbucket.org/danil_minibaev/vedroid-ogl-es2-tutorials/src/c9a5af6d5ec9869ffeef7a968360ba6e639d7929/src/com/airhockey/android/?at=default) code actually

UPD2:

As Reto Koradi noticed I forgot to add `glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);` in code.
I added it and now there are black screen with one white pixel
[image: white pixel]

UPD3:
[last updates are here](https://bitbucket.org/danil_minibaev/vedroid-ogl-es2-tutorials/src/e9cae579c0a7518487a77ba31832c556d3ee6389?at=default)

UPD4:
Errors in output!

> [2014-08-21 18:17:00 - Emulator]
>   sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glAttachShader:156
>   error 0x501 [2014-08-21 18:17:00 - Emulator]
>   sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glValidateProgram:1931
>   error 0x501 [2014-08-21 18:17:00 - Emulator]
>   sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetProgramiv:1148
>   error 0x501 [2014-08-21 18:17:00 - Emulator]
>   sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetProgramiv:1148
>   error 0x501 [2014-08-21 18:17:00 - Emulator]
>   sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetAttribLocation:825
>   error 0x501 [2014-08-21 18:17:00 - Emulator]
>   sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetAttribLocation:825
>   error 0x501

Comment: The code in the linked repo looks different from what you posted here. So it's not clear what you're actually running. One thing I noticed is that the code in the repo requests a config with a depth buffer, but you don't clear the depth buffer. Try changing the clear call to `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I linked to version when it was like worked okay. But it was different way to draw and coloring stuff

Comment: @RetoKoradi and nothing has changed with `glClear` call

Comment: Have you tried on an actual device rather than in the emulator?

Comment: @Zhuinden I got philips w3568, so yep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I see missing is that the code never enables the position vertex attribute. This call should be in `onSurfaceCreated()`, where the vertex attributes are set up:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
```

Comment: well, I added it now there are just white point on black screen :3
http://i.gyazo.com/e8fefc113497a6e4ed3bb4aa3b6e58e9.png

Answer (score 1):

Move `glEnableVertexAttribArray(aColorLocation);` to be below  `glVertexAttribPointer(aColorLocation, COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT,GL_FLOAT,
                false,STRIDE,vertexData);`
and replace it with `glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation)` in your `OnSurfaceCreate`

so that is like the following

```
vertexData.position(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation,POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT,GL_FLOAT,false,STRIDE,vertexData);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);

        vertexData.position(POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT);
        glVertexAttribPointer(aColorLocation,COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT,GL_FLOAT,false,STRIDE,vertexData);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(aColorLocation);
```